# generate New set of Array patterns from loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, object, arraylist

Hi i have one object datatype from that i need to generate New array patterns for filtering the operation, but somehow i could not reach my expected output pattern from the below code, dono where i missing the logic

```
sample code
filterArray = {floor:["floor1","floor2","floor3"],age:[26,23,24],dept:["IT"]}
 var filter = [];
 var groupArray = [];
 for(var key in filterArray){
   var keys = filterArray[key];
   for (value in keys){
    if (keys.length > 1){
      groupArray.push([key, "=",keys[value]]);
      groupArray.push("or");

    }else{
      if (filter.length > 0){
        filter.pop()
        filter.push("and")
        filter.push([key, "=",keys[value]]);
        filter.push("and");  
      }else{
        filter.push([key, "=",keys[value]]);
        filter.push("and");  
      }

    }
}
}
filter.pop()
groupArray.pop()
if (groupArray.length > 0){
filter.push(groupArray);
}
```

**my sample Output**

```
[
 [
    ["floor", "=", "floor1"],
    "or",
    ["floor", "=", "floor2"],
    "or",
    ["floor", "=", "floor3"],
    "or",
    ["age", "=", "26"],
    "or",
    ["age", "=", "23"],
    "or",
    ["age", "=", "24"]
],
"and",
[ "dept", "=", "IT"]
]
```

but my **expected** output is

```
[
[
    ["floor", "=", "floor1"],
    "or",
    ["floor", "=", "floor2"],
    "or",
    ["floor", "=", "floor3"]
],
"and",
 [
    ["age", "=", "26"],
    "or",
    ["age", "=", "23"],
    "or",
    ["age", "=", "24"]
],
"and",
 [ "dept", "=", "IT"]
]
```

i need help to fix this been working this module past two days can anyone resolve my problem will appreciate

(Note: that filter array is genterated dynamically based on user inputs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the keys and then the values of the object to generate the nested arrays of conditions, then use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to insert `or` or `and` as required:

```js
let filterArray = {
  floor: ["floor1", "floor2", "floor3"],
  age: [26, 23, 24],
  dept: ["IT"]
}
let filter = Object.keys(filterArray).map(key => {
  let ors = filterArray[key].map(v => [key, '=', v]);
  let len = ors.length;
  for (let i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    ors.splice(2 * i - 1, 0, 'or');
  }
  return ors;
});
let len = filter.length;
for (let i = 1; i < len; i++) {
  filter.splice(2 * i - 1, 0, 'and');
}
console.log(filter)
```